# How to render an image through |safe filter

Tags: html, django, python-3.x

as I said I need to be able to render an image like...

```
<img src="{% static 'forum/img/Confucius.png' %}" class="responsive-img" style='max-height:200px;' alt="face">
```

everything else in staticfiles like fonts works but safe filter is unable to render an image....
what do I do?

Comment: I don't see a safe filter?

Comment: and why would you need one anyway?